# Angular 6/7 Auxiliary outlet navigating to by route - clears primary outlet and it shouldn't

Tags: angular, routes, lazy-loading, angular-auxiliary-routes

Lazy loading and using named outlets.  I have gotten the named outlet to load as expected but when it does, it is also clearing the primary outlet.  I want the primary outlet to keep the component it is displaying and just the named outlet to change to show new component.

Thanks to some help from @pixelbits... here is an example of what is not working https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sw6cmc

I don't want the primary outlet to change.

The html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="dialogOutlet"></router-outlet>
```

The route:

```
 {    
    path: 'packoutdialog'
    , children:[
      {path:'', outlet:'dialogOutlet', component: PackoutComponent}]

  },
```

Either of these will fill the dialogOutlet but clear the primary

```
 this.router.navigate(['inventory', 'packoutedialog'])
this.router.navigate(['packoutdialog',{outlets:{'dialogOutlet':[]}}],{skipLocationChange: true, relativeTo: this.activatedRoute.parent});
```

This seems like it should work but does not.

```
this.router.navigate([{outlets:{'dialogOutlet':['inventory','packoutdialog']}}])
```

the expected result is that the primary router-outlet keeps the view in it and only the named outlet changes.  Currently the named outlet is changing as expected but the primary outlet is getting cleared.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you have primary outlets and auxiliary outlets together, you need to make sure that both routes fully resolve to a component.  In fact, you should consider each route path in isolation.

For example, if you have a component which sets up a router outlet, and a named router outlet:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="dialogOutlet"></router-outlet>
```

Then you need to make sure that each route can resolve to a component:

```
{ path: 'inventory', component: InventoryComponent, children: [...] }, 
{ path: 'packoutdialog', component: PackoutComponent, outlet: 'dialogOutlet' }
```

Notice that the `packoutdialog` route for the named outlet `dialogOutlet` needs to be defined at the root level. If you defined the named outlet as a child route, it would never resolve.

To navigate to these routes:

```
this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { primary: 'inventory', dialogOutlet: 'packoutdialog'} }]);
```

The primary route will resolve to the InventoryComponent and the named outlet will resolve to the PackoutComponent.

To clear the dialog, you could specify a path for both explicitly:

```
this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { primary: 'inventory', dialogOutlet: null}]);
```

Or, if you want to be able show the `dialogOutlet` regardless of the primary route, you can navigate without explicitly defining a primary route:

```
this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { dialogOutlet: 'packoutdialog'}]);
```

Then to clear the dialog:

```
this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { dialogOutlet: null }]);
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vmikc2)

The above also works for lazy loaded modules.

[Demo with Lazy Module 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vwxvzz)
[Demo with Lazy Module 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-arhmvb)

Comment: that would be great but this - { path: 'packoutdialog', component: PackoutComponent, outlet: 'dialogOutlet' } - doesn't work when you have lazy loading.  I found the trick of having the empty child with the outlet here https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10981#issuecomment-301787482 .  Once I do it with the empty child, it does work but I Only want to change the outlet router box and just don't want the primary one to change at all.  I don't want to refill it, I just want it to remain with what ever it has.

Comment: you can see in my question that I have tried this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { dialogOutlet: 'packoutdialog'}]); and other itterations of it that I think should work and it doesn't.  I believe that is the problem.  With my route, I can't figure out how to call it using the outlets syntax.  It does go to the outlet using the parent route but then the primary gets cleared.

Comment: This also works with lazy loaded modules.  Check the demo link above.

Comment: Interesting... I tried to play with it to show what I am trying to do.  I was unsuccessful in the short amount of time I have right now.  I want the secondary to change without changing the primary and the primary and secondary components are part of the lazy loaded module.  I really appreciate all your time. I will return to this to layout the issue - hopefully tomorrow.  Thank you so much for taking your time.  I really do want to understand this better and get to the bottom of what I am (hopefully) doing wrong.  It may be here.  I promise to return to it soon.

Comment: I was able to replicate my issue https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sw6cmc  I took your demo and moved foo, component1 and component2 to the lazy loading module.  I proved that if it doesn't have the secondary outlet, it does work and if it has the secondary outlet, it doesn't.  Please let me know what I am missing here.

Comment: trying to get what is here stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sw6cmc  to work is what lead me to the hack that lead to the question I posted which is the issue with the hack.  If I can get stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sw6cmc  to work then I am golden.  If I can't, I would at least like to understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: Got your use case to work: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vcqged. Moved 'secondary' named outlet to app-module level, and removed it from the lazy module

Comment: You are wonderful!!!  Thank you.  That is the piece I was missing.  If you have a favorite project I can donate to, just let me know.  You just saved me from a very ugly work around.